# Javascript code that hide textbox based on another textbox value

Tags: javascript, html

If the input isnt a one digit number it has to hide other textboxes. 
I tried this ,but I dont know why it doesnt hide other textboxes.

```js
function validateNum(value){
  var num = Number(value);
  if (num >= 1 && num <= 9) {


    function kk1() {
      document.getElementById("text").disabled = false;

    }

    function kkk1() {
      document.getElementById("group").disabled = false;
    }
  }
  else{
    alert("Please enter only number.");
    function kk1() {
      document.getElementById("text").disabled = true;

    }

    function kkk1() {
      document.getElementById("group").disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? And you don't really need functions for `kk1` `kkk1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
function validateNum(value) {
    var num = Number(value);
    if (num >= 1 && num <= 9) {

        document.getElementById("text").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("group").disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("text").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("group").disabled = true;

        alert("Please enter only number.");
    }
}
```

Allow me to point out a couple things.  First off, this:

```
function kk1() {
  document.getElementById("group").disabled = true;
}
```

defines the function, but does not invoke the function. For invoking, you can either call it: `kk1();` or wrap it to immediately invoke while defining it (IIFE):

```
(function kk1() {
    document.getElementById("group").disabled = true;
})();
```

Also, be careful with this line:

```
var num = Number(value);
```

if the value is not a number, your variable will be `NaN` (which, unfortunately is of type `number`). It may be better to check if it is a number, something like this:

```
if (isNaN(value)) {
    //value is NOT a number
}
else //value is a number
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code below on how you can disable the fields.

In you question it mentioned you wanted to hide the fields

Disable:-

```js
function validateNum(){
var x = document.getElementById("number").value
  var num = Number(x);
  if (num > 0 && num < 10) {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("group").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("group").disabled = true;
    alert("Please enter only a number between 1-9.");
  }
}
```

```css
#text, #group {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="validateNum()" id="number" type="number">

<input id="text">
<input id="group">
```

Hide:-

```js
function validateNum(){
var x = document.getElementById("number").value
  var num = Number(x);
  if (num > 0 && num < 10) {
    document.getElementById("text").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("group").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("group").style.display = "none";
    alert("Please enter only a number between 1-9.");
  }
}
```

```css
#text, #group {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="validateNum()" id="number" type="number">

<input id="text">
<input id="group">
```

Hope this helps